Implementing a Queue using Two Stacks: Enqueue vs. Dequeue Efficiency
I'm implementing a FIFO queue using two stacks and I've come across two methods: one where enqueue operations are costly (moving elements between stacks during enqueue) and another where dequeue operations are costly (moving elements during dequeue). Can someone explain the practical advantages and disadvantages of each method, and in what scenarios one might be preferred over the other?

@user555045 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77090392/what-is-the-point-of-two-stack-based-queues/77092410#77092410

@user555045 It certainly is practical for implementing a queue with a find minimum operation.

The proper way to implement a queue with two stacks is:

Enqueue just pushes an item onto stack 1
Dequeue checks to see if stack 2 is empty.  If it is, then it moves all the items from stack 1 to stack 2, which reverses their order.  Then it pops from stack 2.

You are correct that Dequeue sometimes takes O(n) time, but the amortized cost of both operations is O(1), which actually makes this very fast.
